# How can one input uncommon logic gates in C#?

Tags: c#, logic

I know that you can use `||` for OR and `&&` for AND, and `!` essentially means NOT,  but what about the other logic gates, such as NOR, XOR, etc.?

Comment: There is a build in operator for [xor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/xor-operator)

Comment: !(a || b)- NOR, !(a && b)- NAND , a ^ b - xor

Comment: That's like asking how, given the set of arithmetic operators, you divide the result of an addition. Easy: Figure out what you want to do and write code that does that.

Comment: Also, for non-numeric comparisons, the xor is just !=

Comment: Annoyingly, !| and !& will compile and not throw a runtime error, though they will cause semantic errors since those operators don't do what you would think (they just do OR and AND, respectively).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply build the more complicated logic expressions from the ones you have.

NOR would be `(!x && !y)`

XOR would be `(x && !y) || (!x && y)`

> As @AleksAndreev points out there is also an XOR operator `^`

Answer (score 5):

The only logical infix operators in C# are:

- `|` logical OR (this operator always evaluates both operands)
- `||` conditional OR (If the first operand is true, then C# does not evaluate the second operand)
- `&` logical AND (this operator always evaluates both operands)
- `&&` conditional AND (If the first operand is false, then C# does not evaluate the second operand)
- `^` XOR

The 'not' operator is a prefix operator:

- `!` NOT

To perform logical operations that are similar to other logic gates you would have to use a combination of logical operators, e.g.:

- `!(A && B)` NAND
- `!(A || B)` NOR
- `!(A ^ B)` XNOR

Answer (score 1):

For XOR you can use the `^` symbol

> ```
> // Logical exclusive-OR
> // When one operand is true and the other is false, exclusive-OR 
> // returns True.
> Console.WriteLine(true ^ false);
> // When both operands are false, exclusive-OR returns False.
> Console.WriteLine(false ^ false);
> // When both operands are true, exclusive-OR returns False.
> Console.WriteLine(true ^ true);
> ```
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/xor-operator

For NOR you can use a combination of `!` and `||`